# How to set a flag by qualifying multiple flag fields

Tags: sql

I'm trying to set SQL condition for a QualifierFlag field based on a multiple flag values but couldnt find the right solution for it. Lets say if the flags are A,B,C,D,E and their values are 1 or 0. Now if the value set as 1 for more than one Flag then i have to set the QualifierFlag value as 1 else 0.

This is the first time I am working in SQL development so if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I have removed all those conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms you're actually using.

Answer (score 2):

Just use :

```
 select case 
        when ( A + B + C + D + E <= 1 ) then 0
        else 1  
      end QualifierFlag 
   from mytable;
```

Comment: @jarlh thank you, you're faster than me to fix the typo :)